# youtube live api event tagging, video clipping, preroll ads

Tags: api, events, youtube, live, tagging

I'd like to use YouTube Live to stream a live video embedded in my website.  I'd also like to be able to use the API to tag events within that video based on the time, then auto-generate clips x seconds before and y seconds after the timestamp to show that event only.  I'd also like to publish my own pre-roll advertisements on both the live stream and the clips (and be able to play an ad during the stream at appropriate times).  Is any/all of this possible?

Comment: yes it is. you have to use the youtube livestreaming api